# how to repeat a task till certain time or till an answer has been received?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I want my ui thread to run an ansycTask (e.g. getting current Location)

However i want to limit it by time .how would you suggest doing this?

I have thought triggering a timer, but i'm not sure how.

in addition if i wanted to repeat an asyncTask that returns boolean value

and i want to give it 3 times retry chance.

how can i implement this?

I have thought about doing a few post with checking a static flag indicating an answer was received already, but i'm not sure this is the right way.

Answer (score 0):

One way to [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html). This will allow you to run a thread at scheduled times. You can use methods `scheduleWithFixedDelay` to run your task at specified time.

Create your task by implementing `Runnable`. Use the Executor method `scheduleWithFixedDelay(Runnable command, 
long initialDelay, 
long delay, 
TimeUnit unit)`

The executore will execute your task after the time you have specified. In your task, you can check for if the task is should retry or not. Once your conditions is satisfied or you have reached retries, you can cancel the task. You can use the `shutdown` method to end your task.

Simple class to accomplish this:

```
class RetryTask implements Runnable {
 int retries = 3;
 @Override
 public void run() {
  if(--retries == 0) {
    //shutdown
  }
  if(location recieved) {
   //shutdown
  }
  //else do your task
 }
}
```